# How to make a simple menu in bash from an associative array

Tags: bash, shell-script, menu, associative-array

I am refactoring a script that displays a text menu similar to this:

```
Select a mounted BTRFS device on your local machine to backup to.
1) 123456789abc-def012345-6789abcdef012 (/)
2) 123456789abc-def012345-6789abcdef012 (/home)
...
26) 3e3456789abc-def012345-6789abcdef369 (/mnt/backup2)
27) 223456789abc-def012345-6789abcdef246 (/mnt/backup3)
```

**Note that the menu displays two items of information: the UUID and the target path.** Replicating that with the `select` command is one of the things I do not know how to do.

In this menu, the user enters a number (e.g. 26) and the script performs a BTRFS send|receive to that device & path. I want the script menu to continue working the same way i.e., to display the UUID plus path and take a simple 1 or 2 digit or char input.

However, I want to refactor the code. I did not write the original code. It uses two arrays to display the menu and to handle the selection.

**I want to use an associative array**. This is purely an exercise for me to gain experience with associative arrays. The script is working as is.

I would like to use the following code which I wrote as a basis for the menu:

```
declare -A UUID_TARGETS

for target in $TARGETS; do
    if ! [[ "$target" =~ ^/mnt|^/backup ]] ; then
        echo "skipped $target"
    else
        UUID_TARGETS["$target"]=$(findmnt -n -t btrfs -o UUID -M "$target")
    fi
done

for target in "${!UUID_TARGETS[@]}"; do
    #testing
    echo UUID [${UUID_TARGETS["$target"]}] has mountpoint [$target]
done
```

The bash `select` command doesn't seem to make the menu I want because **I need two items of information displayed in the menu: the UUID and the target path**. The naive use of `select` like this isn't quite sufficient:

```
PS3="Please enter your choice (q to quit): "
select target in "${!UUID_TARGETS[@]}" "quit";
do
    case "$target" in
        "quit")
            echo "Exited"
            break
            ;;
        *)
            selected_uuid=${UUID_TARGETS["$target"]}
            selected_mnt="$target"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

I'm hoping someone here has **an elegant solution for making a menu like this from an associative array**. I want to do this in bash without extra packages.

In the end, I still need to assign the correct value to `selected_uuid` and `selected_mnt`. The original code does it like this:

```
selected_uuid="${UUIDS_ARRAY[$((disk))]}"
selected_mnt="${TARGETS_ARRAY[$((disk))]}"
```

For reference, here is the whole section of original code:

```
TARGETS="$(findmnt -n -l -t btrfs -o TARGET --list -F /etc/fstab)"
UUIDS="$(findmnt -n -l -t btrfs -o UUID --list -F /etc/fstab)"

declare -a TARGETS_ARRAY
declare -a UUIDS_ARRAY

i=0
disk=-1
disk_count=0
for x in $UUIDS; do
    UUIDS_ARRAY[$i]=$x
    if [[ "$x" == "$uuid_cmdline" ]]; then
        disk=$i
        disk_count=$(($disk_count+1))
    fi
    i=$((i+1))
done

i=0
for x in $TARGETS; do
    TARGETS_ARRAY[$i]=$x
    i=$((i+1))
done

if [[ "$disk_count" > 1 ]]; then
    disk="-1"
fi

if [[ "$disk" == -1 ]]; then
    if [[ "$disk_count" == 0 && "$uuid_cmdline" != "none" ]]; then
        error "A device with UUID $uuid_cmdline was not found to be mounted, or it is not a BTRFS device."
    fi
    if [[ -z $ssh ]]; then
        printf "Select a mounted BTRFS device on your local machine to backup to.\n"
    else
        printf "Select a mounted BTRFS device on $remote to backup to.\n"
    fi
    while [[ $disk -lt 0 || $disk -gt $i ]]; do
        for x in "${!TARGETS_ARRAY[@]}"; do
            printf "%4s) %s (%s)\n" "$((x+1))" "${UUIDS_ARRAY[$x]}" "${TARGETS_ARRAY[$x]}"
        done
        printf "%4s) Exit\n" "0"
        read -r -p "Enter a number: " disk
        if ! [[ $disk == ?(-)+([0-9]) ]]; then
            printf "\nNo disk selected. Select a disk to continue.\n"
            disk=-1
        fi
    done
    if [[ $disk == 0 ]]; then
        exit 0
    fi
    disk=$(($disk-1))
fi

selected_uuid="${UUIDS_ARRAY[$((disk))]}"
selected_mnt="${TARGETS_ARRAY[$((disk))]}"
printf "\nYou selected the disk with UUID %s.\n" "$selected_uuid" | tee $PIPE
printf "The disk is mounted at %s.\n" "$selected_mnt" | tee $PIPE
```

Comment: Why not create a new array with the merged entries, i.e. `123456789abc-def012345-6789abcdef012 (/)` and do the "naive select" on that array?

Comment: @icarus I guess I could, but I was looking for a solution that didn't need another array (if such a solution exists). I was just hoping to learn of an elegant solution, if there is one.